# Error: submit tx failed: Error: 400: 0: "278ad827cb923ed800fcb2028114ee8e9bca875059e1389ca1f49755c1c9a629"

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

this.API.submitTx is throwing error
Error: submit tx failed: Error: 400:
0: "278ad827cb923ed800fcb2028114ee8e9bca875059e1389ca1f49755c1c9a629"

```
at checkResponseNoError (apiDom.ts:334:1)
at Object.submitTx (apiDom.ts:270:1)
```

Comment: Is 278ad827cb923ed800fcb2028114ee8e9bca875059e1389ca1f49755c1c9a629 one of your input UTxOs? Do you recognise this hash? Help us to help you.

Comment: An alternative to avoid building transaction in front-end https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7636/117